# Do we know anything about events after Kate & Leopold?

Tags: kate-and-leopold

The 2001 movie Kate & Leopold is a light time-travel romance with a happily ever after.

However, the plot leaves a lot unresolved. Kate is stuck in the past without any way home should Leopold not be the best husband or the past not as romantic as she'd like it to be. In the present, it appears she committed suicide in front of her brother, and has left her loved ones' lives in disarray. [This webpage](https://discover.hubpages.com/entertainment/5-Reasons-Why-The-End-of-Kate-and-Leopold-Is-Actually-Pretty-Depressing) has a good summary of the problems with the end of the movie.

Do we have any canonical information - from a novelization, or early drafts, or interviews with film cast or any other source - about events after what is shown on screen?

Comment: The film already makes no sense.  You want a follow up?

Comment: The novelisation Kate und Leopold has Leopold leaving Charlie a tidy sum of money ($50,000)